# append jquery with forms

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to append my jQuery form value to my table under ‍‍‍‍`<td>` tags.

However for some reason it wont append or post the value inside the table.

here's my jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('form').submit(function(){

    var fname= $('input#form_fname').val(),
        lname = $('input#form_lname').val(),
        email = $('input#form_email').val(),
        phone = $('input#form_phone').val();

    $('tr').append('<td>'.fname.'</td>');

   });
});
```

Here's the JSFIDDLE: https://jsfiddle.net/zbb6fqtc/

Any idea?

Comment: Possible duplicate question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/171027/add-table-row-in-jquery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 problems.

1. In JavaScript for string concatenation you should use the `+` operator  not `.`.
2. You don't prevent the default action of the event. The page is submitted/refreshed and you don't see the appended element.

   ```
   $('form').submit(function(event) {
       event.preventDefault();
       var fname= $('input#form_fname').val();
       // ...
       $('tr').append('<td>' + fname + '</td>');
   });
   ```

> `$('tr').append('<td>' + fname + '</td>');` ->>>>>this part is messing up the table. Any idea why?

Your markup is invalid. You should wrap the `th` elements with a `tr` element. Browsers usually fix the markup. So the `$('tr')` element selects the `tr` child of the `thead` element. You should use a more specific selector for selecting the `tr` child of the `tbody` element. Something like `$('tbody tr')` or `$('tr').eq(1)`.

> Is there a better option to append this?

I would add  empty cells to the `tr` element and populate the cells using the `input` values.

```
<table border="1">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>First Name</th>
            <th>Last Name</th>
            <th>Email Address</th>
            <th>Contact #</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

JavaScript:

```
$('form').submit(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var $td = $('tbody tr td');
    $('input', this).each(function (i) {
        $td.eq(i).text(this.value);
    });
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/zbb6fqtc/9/

Comment: $('tr').append('<td>' + fname + '</td>'); ->>>>>this part is messing up the table. Any idea why? Is there a better option to append this?

Answer (score 1):

just small problems in your js, fixed,tested and works 100%...code below problems

> 1) string concatenation problem, its "+" for js and "." for php
>     2)added event.preventdefault() for preventing default submitting

```
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(event){

            $('form').submit(function(event){
                event.preventDefault();
                var fname= $('input#form_fname').val(),
                    lname = $('input#form_lname').val(),
                    email = $('input#form_email').val(),
                    phone = $('input#form_phone').val();

                $('tr').append('<td>'+fname+'</td>');

            });
        });

    </script>
```

Comment: perhaps highlight what the problems were - rather than just have the OP copy/paste..

Answer (score 0):

Change Button type submit to button.

```
        <p>
            <input type="button" id="bnSubmit" value="Add User" />
        </p>
```

Write your code on jQuery button click event:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

   $("#bnSubmit").click(function(){

  var fname= $('input#form_fname').val(),
        lname = $('input#form_lname').val(),
        email = $('input#form_email').val(),
        phone = $('input#form_phone').val();

    $('tr').append('<td>'+fname+'</td>');

    });

});
```

Note: Replace "." with "+" -->  $('tr').append(''+fname+'');

https://jsfiddle.net/zbb6fqtc/5/

Answer (score 0):

Well you must to prevent submit first.

```
 $('form').submit(function(e){
     e.preventDefault(); //Prevent submit

 });
```

and maybe if you want add more than one tr to that table maybe you need use another selector like this

```
$('table tbody').append('<tr><td>'+fname+'</td>  <td>'+lname+' </tr>');
```